# Where to find WPF Classic Theme as XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes

I am creating some custom controls in WPF and need to therefore create the default control templates for them. To help in this process I would like to see the XAML of the control templates for the builtin controls as a reference.

I can open up the PresentationFramework.Class dll into .NET Reflector but cannot find anything inside it of use. It seems to have only BAML but not the original XAML.

Is this available online somewhere? Or is there a tool that can extract it?

Comment: See also "Where can I download Microsoft's standard WPF themes from?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158678/where-can-i-download-microsofts-standard-wpf-themes-from

Comment: If sample control template are inadequate, you can find the default WPF themes here: [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=158252](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=158252)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have Expression Blend installed several themes, including classic.xaml, can be found in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Blend 3\SystemThemes\Wpf

Comment: If you have the Windows SDK installed they are also available in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Samples\WPFSamples.zip in the Core folder e.g. Core\ClassicTheme\xaml\classic.xaml

Comment: You can download these files directly from MSDN, without Blend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358533.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you need to build new templates the sample control templates at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx are often a better starting point.

The actual themes included with WPF are not designed to be extendable or understandable

Comment: Thank you for the link, I was going crazy with the built-in template source!

Answer (score 3):

The [BAML to XAML Viewer](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins/Wiki/View.aspx?title=BamlViewer&referringTitle=Home) add-in for Reflector can extract the BAML, convert it to XAML and you can also save it to file.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [StyleSnooper](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/02/wpf-tools-stylesnooper/). It allows you to pick any of the inbuilt controls and dump out the default style xaml.

(You can also do this from Expression Blend if you have it.)

Comment: Snoop can also do this - very lightweight, easy to use and has a few other features such as 3D zooming and heirarchy views:
http://blois.us/Snoop/