# Where can I download Microsoft's standard WPF themes from?

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes

Microsoft has made their Classic, Luna, Royale, and Aero themes for WPF available for download as XAML resource dictionaries.

Where can I download them from? I can never find the link!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The download links are identical between .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5--only the online documentation is different.

#### [Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358533%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for .NET 3.0

- [Classic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358537%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ([download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/6/e/f6e32974-726e-4054-96af-9c747bf89a6e/ClassicTheme.exe))
- [Luna](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972127%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ([download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/6/e/f6e32974-726e-4054-96af-9c747bf89a6e/LunaTheme.exe))
- [Royale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972136%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ([download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/6/e/f6e32974-726e-4054-96af-9c747bf89a6e/RoyaleTheme.exe))
- [Aero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972144%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ([download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/6/e/f6e32974-726e-4054-96af-9c747bf89a6e/AeroTheme.exe))

#### [Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358533%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for .NET 3.5

- [Classic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358537%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) ([download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/6/e/f6e32974-726e-4054-96af-9c747bf89a6e/ClassicTheme.exe))
- [Luna](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972127%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) ([download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/6/e/f6e32974-726e-4054-96af-9c747bf89a6e/LunaTheme.exe))
- [Royale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972136%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) ([download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/6/e/f6e32974-726e-4054-96af-9c747bf89a6e/RoyaleTheme.exe))
- [Aero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972144%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) ([download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/6/e/f6e32974-726e-4054-96af-9c747bf89a6e/AeroTheme.exe))

#### [WPF Documentation Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples) for .NET 4 and .NET 4.5

- <s>[Themes](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#themes) ([download](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7812))</s> (No longer available)
- [Classic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa358537.aspx)
- [Luna](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa972127.aspx)
- [Royale](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa972136.aspx)
- [Aero](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa972144.aspx)

Comment: These themes have changed from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.5 (you can see this by decompiling the installed assemblies, look at the template for `ListView` and there is an extra condition to account for the `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping` property) however I cannot find a corresponding download for the updated themes - any idea where they can be found?

Comment: I second Justin, where are they? For example I can't find the ribbon stuff.

Comment: Ribbon wasn't in the original library. That was a separate library from Microsoft specifically for that control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The links are broken and are also missing the Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 themes, where can I get those?

Comment: @bitbonk I've fixed the links. I don't believe Microsoft has released WPF themes for Windows 8 or 10. Feel free to update the answer if you discover any.

Comment: None of the links work anymore and therefore these xaml's don't seem to be available anymore. Pity.

Comment: In *Developer Command Prompt*

`$env:VSINSTALLDIR\DesignTools\SystemThemes\Wpf`

a.k.a.

`%VSINSTALLDIR%\DesignTools\SystemThemes\Wpf`

which is usually like

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\DesignTools\SystemThemes\Wpf`