# Styling the indeterminate state of a WPF checkbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, styles

I want to style the indeterminate state of a WPF checkbox. We have a treeview control with checkboxes, and we want the indeterminate state to represent that some descendants are checked and some are unchecked.

The solution I'm seeing everywhere is to override the default control template for a checkbox and do what I need to do.

I have two problems with that:

1. I can't find the control template
   for a normal Aero checkbox. This
   one:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319.aspx
   looks goofy.
2. The control template I get from Expression Blend has that BulletChrome element in it, and I can't figure out what to do with that.

So does anyone know where to get a checkbox control template that looks "normal" or is there an easier way to just style the indeterminate state by itself?

I'm sure there's an easy way I'm just overlooking... Right?

Comment: I have a feeling that is not as easy as one might think, maybe impossible even without rebuilding the whole bulletchrome-style manually...

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of, but even then -- does anyone have that style already built somewhere? That would help out immensely...

Answer (score 3):

Try this (modified from the article that publicgk linked to)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CheckRadioFocusVisual">
      <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0"
                       StrokeThickness="1"
                       Stroke="Black"
                       StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="EmptyCheckBoxFocusVisual">
      <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="1"
                       StrokeThickness="1"
                       Stroke="Black"
                       StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxFillNormal"
                     Color="#F4F4F4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxStroke"
                     Color="#8E8F8F"/>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type CheckBox}"
         TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
      <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxFillNormal}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxStroke}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="1"/>
      <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
            Value="{StaticResource EmptyCheckBoxFocusVisual}"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" 
                             SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
              <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <theme:BulletChrome Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                    RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                                    IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}"/>
              </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
              <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </BulletDecorator>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsChecked" 
                       Value="{x:Null}">
                <!-- TODO: Do Stuff Here -->
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="HasContent"
                       Value="true">
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                        Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFocusVisual}"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding"
                        Value="4,0,0,0"/>
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                       Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="Checked"/>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Null}" Content="Unknown"/>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="False" Content="Not Checked"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried to download the Aero Theme xaml and looked into it?

[Where can I download Microsoft's standard WPF themes from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158678/where-can-i-download-microsofts-standard-wpf-themes-from)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CheckBox` styling from the classic theme located at:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Expression\Blend 4\SystemThemes\Wpf\classic.xaml`

This implementation has a `Path` representing the checkbox mark called `CheckMarkPath`.  I simply replaced this `Path` with a filled `Rectangle` to get these results:

[image: Checkboxes]

Answer (score 1):

Call me crazy, but I've actually reimplemented standard Aero checkbox in pure XAML. If you want to customize Aero checkbox, it's a good starting point. You can find other styles in [my repository on GitHub](https://github.com/Athari/WpfThemeGenerator/tree/master/Alba.WpfThemeGenerator/Themes/AeroAlt/Controls) ([specific commit](https://github.com/Athari/WpfThemeGenerator/tree/d5bf2018e70e21ca33e58657920789a15af9613e/Alba.WpfThemeGenerator/Themes/AeroAlt/Controls), in case files are moved).

**BulletCommon.xaml** *(common resources for CheckBox and RadioButton)*

```
<ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xx="clr-namespace:Alba.WpfThemeGenerator.Markup">

    <!-- Colors -->

    <!-- Background overlay -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Bullet.BackgroundOverlay.Hover" Color="#DEF9FA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Bullet.BackgroundOverlay.Pressed" Color="#C2E4F6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Bullet.BackgroundOverlay.Disabled" Color="#F4F4F4"/>
    <!-- Border overlay -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Bullet.BorderOverlay.Hover" Color="#3C7FB1"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Bullet.BorderOverlay.Pressed" Color="#2C628B"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Bullet.BorderOverlay.Disabled" Color="#ADB2B5"/>
    <!-- Inner border -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Bullet.InnerBorder.Disabled" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#E1E3E5" Offset="0.25"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E8E9EA" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <!-- Indeterminate inner border -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Bullet.InnerBorder.IndeterminateDisabled" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#BFD0DD" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#BDCBD7" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#BAC4CC" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <!-- Inner fill -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Bullet.InnerFill.Normal" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#CBCFD5" Offset="0.2"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#F7F7F7" Offset="0.8"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Bullet.InnerFill.Hover" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#B1DFFD" Offset="0.2"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E9F7FE" Offset="0.8"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Bullet.InnerFill.Pressed" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#7FBADC" Offset="0.2"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#D6EDF9" Offset="0.8"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <!-- Indeterminate fill -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Bullet.Fill.Indeterminate" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#2FA8D5" Offset="0.2"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#25598C" Offset="0.8"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Bullet.Fill.IndeterminateHover" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#33D7ED" Offset="0.2"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#2094CE" Offset="0.8"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Bullet.Fill.IndeterminatePressed" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#17447A" Offset="0.2"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#218BC3" Offset="0.8"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Bullet.Fill.IndeterminateDisabled" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#C0E5F3" Offset="0.2"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#BDCDDC" Offset="0.8"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!-- Styles -->

    <Style x:Key="Bullet.FocusVisual.Normal">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{xx:SystemBrush ControlText}" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Bullet.FocusVisual.Empty">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{xx:SystemBrush ControlText}" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**CheckBox.xaml** *(resources for CheckBox)*

```
<ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xx="clr-namespace:Alba.WpfThemeGenerator.Markup">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="BulletCommon.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <!-- Colors -->

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBox.Stroke" Color="#8E8F8F"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBox.Fill" Color="#F4F4F4"/>
    <!-- Check mark -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBox.Glyph.Stroke.Normal" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBox.Glyph.Stroke.Pressed" Color="#B2FFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBox.Glyph.Fill.Normal" Color="#31347C"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBox.Glyph.Fill.Pressed" Color="#B231347C"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBox.Glyph.Fill.Disabled" Color="#AEB7CF"/>
    <!-- Inner border -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckBox.InnerBorder" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#AEB3B9" Offset="0.25"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#C2C4C6" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EAEBEB" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckBox.InnerBorder.Hover" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#79C6F9" Offset="0.3"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#79C6F9" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#D2EDFD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckBox.InnerBorder.Pressed" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#54A6D5" Offset="0.3"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#5EB5E4" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#C4E5F6" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <!-- Indeterminate inner border -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckBox.InnerBorder.Indeterminate" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#2A628D" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#245479" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#193B55" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckBox.InnerBorder.IndeterminateHover" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#29628D" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#245479" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#193B55" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckBox.InnerBorder.IndeterminatePressed" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#193B55" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#245479" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#29628D" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <!-- Indeterminate highlight -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckBox.Highlight.Indeterminate" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#003333A0" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#003333A0" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckBox.Highlight.IndeterminateHover" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#003333A0" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#803333A0" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckBox.Highlight.IndeterminatePressed" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#20FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!-- Images -->

    <PathGeometry x:Key="CheckBox.Glyph.Geometry">
        <PathFigure StartPoint="9.0, 1.833" IsClosed="True">
            <LineSegment Point="10.667, 3.167"/>
            <LineSegment Point="7, 10.667"/>
            <LineSegment Point="5.333, 10.667"/>
            <LineSegment Point="3.333, 8.167"/>
            <LineSegment Point="3.333, 6.833"/>
            <LineSegment Point="4.833, 6.5"/>
            <LineSegment Point="6, 8"/>
        </PathFigure>
    </PathGeometry>

    <!-- Styles -->

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type CheckBox}" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.FocusVisual.Empty}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{xx:SystemBrush ControlText}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.Fill}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.Stroke}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Grid Width="13" Height="13">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Background" Margin="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundOverlay" Margin="0"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="InnerFill" Margin="3" Fill="{StaticResource Bullet.InnerFill.Normal}"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="2" Stroke="{StaticResource CheckBox.InnerBorder}"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Highlight" Margin="3"/>
                                <Path x:Name="GlyphStroke" Margin="0" StrokeThickness="1.5" Data="{StaticResource CheckBox.Glyph.Geometry}"/>
                                <Path x:Name="GlyphFill" Margin="0" Data="{StaticResource CheckBox.Glyph.Geometry}"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Margin="0" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="BorderOverlay" Margin="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </BulletDecorator>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="True">
                            <!-- if (HasContent) -->
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.FocusVisual.Normal}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <!-- if (IsMouseOver) -->
                            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundOverlay" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.BackgroundOverlay.Hover}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerFill" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.InnerFill.Hover}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="BorderOverlay" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.BorderOverlay.Hover}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.InnerBorder.Hover}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <!-- if (IsChecked == null) -->
                            <Setter TargetName="Highlight" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.Highlight.Indeterminate}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerFill" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.Fill.Indeterminate}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.InnerBorder.Indeterminate}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <!-- if (IsPressed) -->
                            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundOverlay" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.BackgroundOverlay.Pressed}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerFill" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.InnerFill.Pressed}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="BorderOverlay" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.BorderOverlay.Pressed}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.InnerBorder.Pressed}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <!-- if (IsChecked == null && IsMouseOver) -->
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="Highlight" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.Highlight.IndeterminateHover}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerFill" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.Fill.IndeterminateHover}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.InnerBorder.IndeterminateHover}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <!-- if (IsChecked == null && IsPressed) -->
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="Highlight" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.Highlight.IndeterminatePressed}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerFill" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.Fill.IndeterminatePressed}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.InnerBorder.IndeterminatePressed}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <!-- if (IsChecked == true && IsPressed) -->
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="GlyphStroke" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.Glyph.Stroke.Pressed}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="GlyphFill" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.Glyph.Fill.Pressed}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <!-- if (IsChecked == true && !IsPressed) -->
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="GlyphStroke" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.Glyph.Stroke.Normal}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="GlyphFill" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.Glyph.Fill.Normal}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <!-- if (!IsEnabled) -->
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{xx:SystemBrush GrayText}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerFill" Property="Fill" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="GlyphStroke" Property="Stroke" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="BorderOverlay" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.BorderOverlay.Disabled}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.InnerBorder.Disabled}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <!-- if (IsChecked == null && !IsEnabled) -->
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerFill" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.Fill.IndeterminateDisabled}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource Bullet.InnerBorder.IndeterminateDisabled}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <!-- if (IsChecked == true && !IsEnabled) -->
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="GlyphFill" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource CheckBox.Glyph.Fill.Disabled}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Notes:**

1. `{xx:SystemBrush ControlText}` is a shortcut for `{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}`. You can either use that [shortcut](https://github.com/Athari/WpfThemeGenerator/blob/d5bf2018e70e21ca33e58657920789a15af9613e/Alba.WpfThemeGenerator/Markup/Extensions/SystemBrushExtension.cs) or just find and replace with regex.
2. RTL, animations, weird cases are not supported.
3. This style is slower than using `BulletChrome` which is heavily optimized.

Comment: Thanks.  This helped, as I couldn't find any other place with BulletChrome template.  One problem is the xmlns:xx="clr-namespace:Alba.WpfThemeGenerator.Markup reference.  I commented it out, and replaced all {xx:SystemBrush ControlText} values with {DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}

Answer (score 0):

The below code is a sample check box with three state.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Focus Style -->

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="InputBackgroundFocused" Color="Orange"></SolidColorBrush>

    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxFocusVisualStyle">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border CornerRadius="2" Margin="0,0,4,3" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource InputBackgroundFocused}" Background="Transparent"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!-- Fill Brushes -->

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalLightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />

    <!-- Border Brushes -->

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DefaultedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#777" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#000" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#888" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

    <!-- Miscellaneous Brushes -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightColorBrush" Color="#DDD" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource CheckBoxFocusVisualStyle}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Border x:Name="Border"  
                              Width="17" 
                              Height="17" 
                              CornerRadius="2" 
                              Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="1"
                              BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}">
                                <Path 
                                Width="11" Height="11" 
                                x:Name="CheckMark"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
                                Stroke="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
                                StrokeThickness="2"
                                Data="M 2,4 C 2,4 3,5 5,13 C 5,13 5,3 12,0" />
                            </Border>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </BulletDecorator>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Data" Value="M 0 7 L 7 0" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <CheckBox>Hello</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox IsThreeState="True">asdfsdaf</CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The best software to modify the existing look and feel of the controls is Expression Blend. If you want to change the existing look and feel and you have to modify the Control Template of the control.

Comment: Still doesn't look like the regular Aero checkbox. I would rather everything stay the same for whatever theme the OS is using. Failing that, I'd rather all checkboxes look like the Aero theme. As I mentioned in my question, I've used Expression Blend, and it doesn't give you the full xaml for the Checkbox. It does a lot of magic inside the BulletChrome control.

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to style a toggle button as it has multiple states as well. In past projects I have created custom toggle buttons with multiple states that look and function as chekcboxes. I did use blend to make the changes but in using a tggle button as the base I was able to create a more customized look and feel for the various states of the button/chekcbox.  Using a toggle button can bypass a lot of the chrome related issues that are tightly boud to a standard chekcbox control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using SimpleStyles as the base for control?

[image: ExpressionSimpleStyles]

By selecting this control from the Assets panel, Expression Blend will place a new resource dictonary in your project that you can use to modify the style as you please. Might be a better starting point than trying to hack into the Chrome for the standard checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Using the template from Blend:

To make BulletChrome work, you need to **add a reference to PresentationFramework.Aero**, and add the xml namespace declaration for the "theme" namespace:

```
xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

I didn't try this myself but I believe it should work (I've done it with Luna).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the checkbox's [`IsThreeState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.isthreestate(v=vs.110).aspx) property to true.

This, however, allows toggling the checkbox's value to null.
If that is undesired, you can instead add to your CheckBox's Template a trigger for the null value, just like Greg Bacchus [shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5935268/148412):

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
        <!-- TODO: Do Stuff Here -->
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```