# Windows 8 WPF progress bars don't have glow animation

Tags: wpf, windows-8, wpf-controls

The progress bars in Windows Forms applications have the standard "shine" animation, but when I try to add a progress bar in WPF I don't get such a thing by default. How do we get this back with WPF in Windows 8?

**Windows Forms**

[image]

**WPF**

[image]

Comment: Note: WPF is correct here. Windows 8 did away with all the gloss.

Comment: You must override ControlTemplate of ProgressBar and provide any animation on your own.

Comment: Daniel, why does Windows 8 have it here? http://puu.sh/3Lk3W.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rather bizzare fix, but you need to enable Windows Forms styles in your application to use the "gloss." Here's how I did it.

1. Add a reference in your project to `System.Windows.Forms`
2. Go to the Project settings page and click `View Application Events`
3. Add a handler to your `Application.Startup` using the following code (in VB.NET, C# similar) (also, if you need to include the arguments, do so)

```vb
Class Application

    ' Application-level events, such as Startup, Exit, and DispatcherUnhandledException
    ' can be handled in this file.

    Private Sub Application_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    End Sub

End Class
```

It seems weird that you would have to call this in order to get the *WPF* progressbar to work, but the code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ultimate control over the look (namely the color of the indicator), I have tweaked a control I found on another SO post, which gives near-identical display.

Tweak:

```
<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <Grid Width="{Binding ProgressBarWidth, ElementName=uc}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" From="-1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Offset)" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Offset)" From="1" To="2" Duration="0:0:1.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF218ED6" Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF4BA5E0" Offset="0.4" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8ECCF5" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF4BA5E0" Offset="0.6" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF218ED6" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Full Implementation:

[Progress bar style in WPF is old fashioned. Increments in Bars. How to implement a progress bar with vista or windows-7 shady glow effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967898/progress-bar-style-in-wpf-is-old-fashioned-increments-in-bars-how-to-implement)

Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Milliron X answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29658093/1548895) didn't help me so I had to use Windows Forms `ProgressBar` instead of reinventing the wheel using custom control.

To achieve this:

1. Add reference to `WindowsFormsIntegration` and `System.Windows.Forms` assemblies.
2. Add following namespace to `Window` element

   ```
   xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
   ```
3. Add `ProgressBar` to `WindowsFormsHost` control. For example

   ```
   <WindowsFormsHost Margin="0,10,0,0">
       <wf:ProgressBar x:Name="DownloadProgressBar" Width="500" Height="50" />
   </WindowsFormsHost>
   ```
4. For our `ProgressBar` not to look "old-style" you need to add following line to your entry point (e.g. `Main` method or `Application.OnStartUp` method):

   ```
   System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   ```