# What are good ways to show a WPF program has not frozen?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I have a WPF program which handles large amounts of data at once which is being done using a `BackgroundWorker`. This updates its progress to a `ProgressBar` but with larger sets of data the bar can often remain static.

What are effective ways of reassuring the user the program hasn't frozen and is still working?

Currently, to reassure myself I have the window's `Title` being each index of this array in turn: `["|", "/", "-", @"\"]`. With a 100 tick delay between each change it creates a sort of ASCII spinner. But I want something better for the actual users.

**EDIT**

Is there an easy way to add the glowing effect to the 'complete' part of the `ProgressBar` you often see?

Comment: Maybe the wait cursor?

Comment: But wouldn't a program that *has* frozen do that?

Comment: Maybe just place a label that says e.g. "This process may take a few minutes..."

Comment: No, you control the cursor.  Wouldn't you want to?  It would be annoying if your application decided when to use whatever cursor.

Comment: @user3075190 Yes, but if you already have a progressBar to show it has not "frozen" then whats the problem?  You can keep changing the cursor from "wait" to "arrow" back to "wait" as you do steps in your methods, maybe?  Can you provide an example of the "glowing effect' you're looking for?

Comment: Agree with @rory.ap here, control the cursor and keep the app responsive (by keeping everything running in a background worker).  You can look at using different animated progress bars.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a UX question, rather than a programming problem.  If you know what UX you want to create and have a problem related to how to implement it, then it may be on topic here.

Comment: I think like when windows copy you can show names or details about whats going on .. I also noticed in one google app, during the download it was showing it like 45.04% because the file was large, which I think is also a good idea

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ebc1c34c-5ef3-4196-9975-8c1cfa0ebbfd/animated-progress-bar?forum=wpf

Comment: @rory.ap No?  You, as a user, don't turn your cursor from an arrow to an hourglass.  You move your cursor around on the screen, and choose when to click it, but it is the application that it's currently hovering over that determines which "mode" the cursor shows as being in.

Comment: @Servy -- UX is a subset of programming.  And the user seems to have a problem.  I've seen questions with a far looser definition of "problem" survive closure.

Comment: BusyIndicator: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Home

Comment: @rory.ap UX design is *not* a subset of programming.  Implementing a particular UX is a subset of programming.  The question isn't asking how to implement a particular UX feature/problem, it's asking how to design the UX.  That's an entirely separate field.

Comment: @Servy -- "You" as in the programmer, not the user (I thought that was pretty obvious).

Comment: JUST READ THIS BLOG: https://elegantcode.com/2011/10/07/extended-wpf-toolkitusing-the-busyindicator/

Comment: @DanAndrews -- woah, settle down.  No need to shout.

Comment: Above all else, keep the UI responsive. This means making background tasks that are running on the UI thread into async operations. If you need to, put up a [busy indicator](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Home) to let the user know that something is happening, but do not block the UI thread, or the thing won't move.

Comment: If you're looking for a glow, this post probably has a good starting point for you.  The answer that shows gradient brushes, with a blue preview.  It looks like it needs some work after the 4th step in his preview, but I think everything you need is in there.  You may need to adjust if you're looking for a 100% glow, or some other display, but if I understand your question right this is a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672058/windows-8-wpf-progress-bars-dont-have-glow-animation

Comment: I have a sense that you actually have frozen the UI. If so, you consider not doing that. You should let the user do other, unrelated things while waiting but always allow at least closing the program.

Comment: @TomBlodget I don't have a frozen UI - Like I said in the question, I have an ASCII spinner in the window's Title, I just want something better for the finished product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible add a second ProgressBar.
One for the overall progress (which you already have) and one for the progress of the current step.

Alternatively, you could put a text somewhere that says "Processing item 1234 of 123123123" that would update with every item that is being processed.
This way the user will see the changing number.

Comment: In the end, I went for a Label over the centre of the Progress Bar with the `(currentByteOfData / 100) + "/" + (totalBytesOfData / 100)`