# Editing the standard WPF Aero theme

Tags: wpf, themes, aero

I want to look into the default styles that are used for the default WPF application so that I can experiment/tweak them. (I believe this to be the standard AERO theme)

So I downloaded the default themes from [Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158678/where-can-i-download-microsofts-standard-wpf-themes-from), and manually applied the AERO theme.

- I added the "Aero.NormalColor.xaml" file into my project
- I then added "PresentationUI.dll" and "PresentationFramework.Aero.dll"
- I then modified the namespace from "xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;" to  "xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" (It was throwing errors otherwise)
- Finally I add it into the Apps resource dictionary

But it ends up looking slightly different, in particular, menus seem to look different. So I guess I'm running the wrong theme.

This is using VS 2010 and the default new .net4 WPF application project

Comment: If you want to customize the default `Style` for a Control, why not just create an element of that type in xaml -> right click on it in "Document Outline" in VS and choose "Edit Template"->"Edit a Copy"?

Comment: Because I want to inspect the AERO theme as a whole, ..see how everything ties together, .. see how it produces the effects it does etc

Comment: Why not just look at the xaml?

Answer (score -1):

Those default themes you downloaded could be god knows what. Probably not what is shipped with the actual .NET framework and Windows.

I don't know what your end goal is, but I would suggest looking at the XAML of a specific control you are interested in Blend. It was a pretty simple action, something like right click -> edit control template, although I can't remember the exact steps (like where to click exactly etc). I'm sure you can google that information very quickly...