# How do I know which systemcolors to use for different controls If I want default classic Window look?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**In my DefaultTheme.xaml File I have only set my colors**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxForegroundColor"                Color="Black"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBackgroundColor"                Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBorderbrushColor"               Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowColorKey}}"/>
```

**In my ColorTheme.xaml I have done the same but different colors**

```
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxForegroundColor"                Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBackgroundColor"                Color="#FF2d2d30"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckboxBorderbrushColor"               Color="#FFCC1517"/>
```

**In my App.xaml**

```
<Setter Property="Foreground"               Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxForegroundColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="Background"               Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxBackgroundColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"              Value="{DynamicResource CheckboxBorderbrushColor}"/>
```

Changing themes at runtime works fine and my ColorTheme works fine also. But my question is how do I know which systemcolors to use for example Button.Foreground and Button.Background to get the windows Classic look? There are so many Systemcolors I get confused and don't know which one to use for different controls. I have set all my colors to WindowsColorKey in my Default.xaml but seems that it is the wrong way to do it because my application becomes white.

Comment: I wouldn't redesign the wheel - if you want the classic theme, it is already available... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075720/windows-7-theme-for-wpf . If you want to view the brushes used, you may have them installed locally... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453853/where-to-find-wpf-classic-theme-as-xaml

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to reset the colors of your `Checkbox`'s...  Something like:

```
public void DefaultColors()
{
    cbBox1.ForeColor = Color.Beige;
    cbBox2.ForeColor = Color.Beige;
    //And so on....
}
```

And run it when you need to.  The object's you create in your .XAML are accessible in the affiliated `.cs` file.  Do it there...

Comment: Why no make it simple and change all my colors to default in my DefaultTheme and then when i change my theme everything changes? Just like i have done with my ColorTheme? Is there no way to set my colors to default in the DefaultTheme.xaml to have that classic window look?

Comment: Create the function to assign the colors, then when you initialize the window, run the function.  If you want to change the colors at runtime to a different theme, you have to have a function like that anyway.  It's not complicated - just repetitive.

Comment: Trust me...  I've done it...  https://github.com/geoffoverfield/MyCalculator/blob/master/Calculator2.7.2/Calculator/Form1.cs

Comment: Guess that's not helpful @A.Game??