# Finding Default WPF Theme File

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, templates, styles

In Visual Studio we can extract default style by right-clicking on the control and choosing Edit Template. My question is where this style comes from? PresentationFramework assembly? How we can get the main theme file which is included all default styles applied to the System.Windows.Controls?

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [Where to find WPF Classic Theme as XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453853/where-to-find-wpf-classic-theme-as-xaml).

From the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453930/7604843) of that question, as well as the comments on it:

If you have Expression Blend installed several themes, including classic.xaml, can be found in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Blend 3\SystemThemes\Wpf
```

If you have the Windows SDK installed they are also available in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Samples\WPFSamples.zip in the Core folder e.g. Core\ClassicTheme\xaml\classic.xaml
```

Additionally, You can download these files directly from MSDN, without Blend: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358533.aspx

Answers from @ChrisF, @PhilDevaney, and @M.Dudley

Comment: I have windows 7 and SDK installed, but there is no WPFSamples.zip file. Also my SDK path is different from the answer and is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits

Comment: Also I can't find any file to download from msdn page.

Answer (score 1):

VS2022 02.2023

`C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/DesignTools/SystemThemes/Wpf`

```
aero.normalcolor.xaml
aero2.normalcolor.xaml
aerolite.normalcolor.xaml
classic.xaml
luna.homestead.xaml
luna.metallic.xaml
luna.normalcolor.xaml
royale.normalcolor.xaml
```