# RenderSize of Grid control have difference in Windows 10 [.NET Framework 4.6.2] and Windows 7[.NET Framework 4]

Tags: wpf, windows-7, grid, windows-10, appearance

I have a custom combo box style as below

```
 <Style x:Key="SmallArrowComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1E1E1E"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#454545"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"                     Value="Segoe UI,Meiryo UI" />
    <Setter Property="Background"                     Value="#1C1C1C" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"                     Value="#FFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup1" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1,0,1,1" Placement="Bottom" >
                        <Border x:Name="Shdw1" BorderBrush ="#FF4289C4" Background="#FF4289C4" BorderThickness="1" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid1}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderThickness="0" Background="#1E1E1E">
                              <Grid>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer1" Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}">
                                    <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect1" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"
                                                       Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                        </Canvas>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter1" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                                <Slider x:Name="CustomSliderVertical" Margin="0,0,-12,0" Maximum="100" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="10" 
                                    Style="{StaticResource CustomSliderStyle}" Foreground="{DynamicResource LimeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Delay="1"
                                    Orientation="Vertical" Focusable="False" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                              </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                    <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                  Style="{StaticResource SmallArrowComboBoxToggleButton}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Name="ContentSite"
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                      IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBoxSmall" Width="150" Height="40"
        Style="{x:Null}" 
        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxSmall}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Margin="3,3,23,3"
        Focusable="True" 
        Background="Transparent"
        Visibility="Hidden"
        IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>

                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBoxSmall" Property="Visibility"    Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="PART_EditableTextBoxSmall" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I prepared a test application with a combo box and applied this style to the combo box.
Prepared the test application with

> .NET Framework 4 and 4.6.2

Tested the appearance of combo box using both

> Windows-10(.NET Framework 4.6.2) and Windows-7(.NET Framework 4)

But there is an appearance difference between Windows 10 and Windows 7.

That is the alignment of combo box text is different.

That is padding of combo box is different in Windows 10 and Windows 7. But these padding values are not explicitly set in the code.

> - In Windows 7, the padding value is ‘4,3,4,3’
> - In Windows 10, the padding value is ‘6,3,5,3’

While checking, it is observed that the `RenderSize` of "MainGrid1" (grid layout control from the above style code) is different in Windows 10 and Windows 7.
From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendersize(v=vs.110).aspx), `RenderSize` is the final render size of an element.

My doubt is why this `RenderSize` have different values in Windows 10 and Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 and Windows 7 use different default themes for WPF controls. Things like buttons and ComboBoxes will look slightly different unless you override the default template and/or change the necessary properties. You can also use Expression blend to "dump" out the default template to see details.

There are a number of other questions about themes if you do a little searching on StackOverflow. ie:
[where-to-find-wpf-classic-theme-as-xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453853/where-to-find-wpf-classic-theme-as-xaml)

Comment: I checked the default control template of combo box in .NET Framework 4(using Blend 2012) and 4.6.2 (using Blend 2017). It is observed that there are some difference in some properties values like BorderThickness and Padding etc. Any idea why this difference ? Is control template updated while changing .NET Frame work ?